# How to capture a printed log from `gnome-terminal -x`?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

When I issue the command `sudo fio myjog | tee mylog` in a terminal window,
I can save the `fio` log into the `mylog` file.

But if I issue the command `sudo gnome-terminal -x sudo fio myjog | tee mylog`, the `mylog` file will be created without any text inside.

How to capture a printed log from `gnome-terminal -x` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each command run in the command line is, in order:

- interpreted by the shell;
- interpreted by the executable;

In this case `|` makes the shell interpret `sudo gnome-terminal -x sudo fio myjog | tee mylog` as two commands piped to each other (`sudo gnome-terminal -x sudo fio myjog` and `tee mylog`, the first one piped to the second one).

The result of this is that the output of `sudo gnome-terminal -x sudo fio myjog` is piped to `tee mylog`; since `gnome-terminal` doesn't output anything, `mylog` is empty.

Use the `-e` option to pass the command to be executed as an argument;

Commands passed through the `-e` options are executed in `sh`;

In this case, since you want to use a pipe, which is a `bash` (and other shells) feature, you'll need to explicitly run the command in `bash` (on a side note: you don't need `sudo` to run `gnome-terminal` if you're going to use `sudo` in the argument to the `-x` / `-e` options):

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"sudo fio myjog | tee mylog\""
```

Comment: It works !!! Thank you for your patience guidance

Comment: @Lenny You're welcome, see also Serg's answer; if you *don't* need to put other commands after the `gnome-terminal` command you may keep using `-x` in the way outlined in his asnwer instead of using `-e`

Answer (score 3):

Ask gnome-terminal to run bash with a specific command. For example,

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c " printf "YOLO"; sleep 5 "
```

In your case, make it

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "sudo fio myjog | tee mylog"
```

Alternative,

ask `script` command to log output instead of `tee`. Example,

```
gnome-terminal -x script -c "sudo apt-get update" myLog
```